# Automatic creation date for Django model form objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

What's the best way to set a creation date for an object automatically, and also a field that will record when the object was last updated?

**models.py:**

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(False, True, editable=False)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(True, True, editable=False)
```

**views.py:**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('obj_list')
```

I get the error:

```
objects_object.created_at may not be NULL
```

Do I have to manually set this value myself? I thought that was the point of the parameters passed to `DateTimeField` (or are they just defaults, and since I've set `editable=False` they don't get displayed on the form, hence don't get submitted in the request, and therefore don't get put into the form?).

What's the best way of doing this? An `__init__` method?

Answer (score 478, accepted):

You can use the [`auto_now`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [`auto_now_add`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) options for `updated_at` and `created_at` respectively.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: it produces this error:
`You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'created_at' to gameuser without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> timezone.now()`

Comment: delete  the rows on the databas, or  check option 1 and  add  timezone.now()

Comment: Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> timezone.now()
Migrations for 'aml_validations':

Comment: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present-- Migration error

Comment: [Django REST Framework seems to think this is a fine approach](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#auto_now-and-auto_now_add-model-fields).

Comment: I think @gregoltsov's comment is out of date at this point. Using `auto_now_add` or `auto_now` works just fine. It sets the field before saving the model (https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1343).

Comment: @gregoltsov comment is outdated as [another answer to the same question he mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330128/2281751) states.

Comment: Thanks @yndolok and Dandelion - I've removed my comment so it doesn't confuse people landing on this answer!

Answer (score 115):

Well, the above answer is correct, [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) and [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) would do it, but it would be better to make an abstract class and use it in any model where you require `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

```
class TimeStampMixin(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now anywhere you want to use it you can do a simple inherit and you can use timestamp in any model you make like.

```
class Posts(TimeStampMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    ...
```

In this way, you can leverage object-oriented reusability, in Django DRY(don't repeat yourself)

Comment: Very soon you find yourself with 7 layers of inheritance not understanding what the devil is going on... or better yet 7 layers of inheritance collapsed into one class with the name "Utility".

Comment: @Spidey I'm conflicted about your comment: on one hand I very much agree that abstraction abuse (especially the OOP flavored one) is more often than not a bad thing. However in this case, it seems to me like a case of "good (because it's predictable and generally useful) pattern / practice encapsulation", which is, when you think about it, the essence of frameworks like Django and such.

Comment: @cjauvin I understand your position, I've been there myself but I honestly think this example falls under `composition over inheritance`. Taking inspiration from libs/frameworks is okay, but remember that project code doesn't need to be as reusable. It needs to be quickly modifiable though and adding layers of inheritance can hurt in that regard.

Comment: if everybody had that mindset we'd never have taken off from assembly.