# Automatic Time and Date Insertion

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to automatically add the date and time information of that time to a certain field in the project I am doing. I am using Django, HTML, JavaScript in my project, how can I do it with any of them?

Comment: duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429878/automatic-creation-date-for-django-model-form-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429878/automatic-creation-date-for-django-model-form-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define in models:

```
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```