# Django admin: How to display the field marked as "editable=False" in the model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Even though a field is marked as `'editable=False'` in the model, I would like the admin page to display it. Currently, it hides the field altogether.. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Use [Readonly Fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields). Like so (for django >= 1.2):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('first',)
```

Comment: +1. Especially if you _don't_ plan to edit the field at all in Admin.

Comment: This does not work here (Django 2.0). The field is not displayed then in the  admin interface.

Comment: I just created a sample application to reproduce your error (django 2.0.8, python 3.5). This still works fine. Maybe something else is wrong in your app @nerdoc?

Comment: oOops. Typical fast-shot. Did not test, seems to be a problem with my installation. Thanks, and sorry.

Comment: For me admin crashed when I added it to `fields`, but when I added it to `readonly_fields` it didn't show up until I added it to both and then it appeared in admin.

Comment: To confirm @nerdoc make sure you add 'MyModelAdmin' to the admin.site.register(...) it should work. If it doesn't you have other issues.

Answer (score 19):

**Update**

This solution is useful if you want to keep the field editable in Admin but non-editable everywhere else. If you want to keep the field non-editable *throughout* then @Till Backhaus' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967644/django-admin-how-to-display-a-field-that-is-marked-as-editablefalse-in-the-mod/3967891#3967891) is the better option.

**Original Answer**

One way to do this would be to use a custom `ModelForm` in admin. This form can override the required field to make it editable. Thereby you retain `editable=False` everywhere else but Admin. For e.g. (tested with Django 1.2.3)

```
# models.py
class FooModel(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length = 255, editable = False)
    second  = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.first, self.second)

# admin.py
class CustomFooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = FooModel
        fields = ('second',)

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomFooForm

admin.site.register(FooModel, FooAdmin)
```

Comment: This does not work, at least on django 1.6 The form is displayed correctly in the admin panel, but when I save a form and return to it again, the forms value is default again.

Answer (score 14):

Add the fields you want to display on your admin page.

Then add the fields you want to be read-only.

Your read-only fields must be in `fields` as well.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'published_date', 'updated_date', 'created_date']
    readonly_fields = ('updated_date', 'created_date')
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue for me. I simply put the `readonly_fields` on top and let `fields` be the editable fields `+ readonly_fields` (both are tuples in my code; I don't see why one would declare them as lists).

Answer (score 5):

You could also set the readonly fields as `editable=False` in the model (django doc reference for `editable` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#editable)). And then in the Admin overriding the `get_readonly_fields` method.

```py
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
  first = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False)

# admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    return [f.name for f in obj._meta.fields if not f.editable]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the above solution I was able to display hidden fields for several objects but got an exception when trying to add a new object.

So I enhanced it like follows:

```
class HiddenFieldsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    try:
        return [f.name for f in obj._meta.fields if not f.editable]
    except:
        # if a new object is to be created the try clause will fail due to missing _meta.fields
        return ""
```

And in the corresponding admin.py file I just had to import the new class and add it whenever registering a new model class

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Example, HiddenFieldsAdmin

admin.site.register(Example, HiddenFieldsAdmin)
```

Now I can use it on every class with non-editable fields and so far I saw no unwanted side effects.

Comment: I'm surprised how well this works actually!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@admin.register(AgentLinks)
class AgentLinksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('link', )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display `editable=False` fields with [readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('updated_date', 'created_date')
```

And, if assigning `editable=False` fields to [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields), you also need to assign them to `readonly_fields` as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('updated_date', 'created_date')
    readonly_fields = ('updated_date', 'created_date')
```

Because, if only assigning `editable=False` fields to `fields` without assigning them to `readonly_fields` as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('updated_date', 'created_date')
    # readonly_fields = ('updated_date', 'created_date')
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'updated_date' cannot be specified
> for MyModel model form as it is a non-editable field. Check
> fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class MyModelAdmin.