# django admin not showing abstract base class fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have

```
class BaseModelMixin(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False, blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False, blank=True)
```

and

```
class Something(BaseModelMixin):
    whatever = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class SomethingElse(BaseModelMixin):
    whoever = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

on the admin site, for each Something, I see whatever, but not uuid, created_on, or updated_on. I must be missing something obvious... it'd be surprising if the django admin didn't automatically show me these fields.

I definitely want the abstract; I don't want an additional table, I want the uuid, created_on, updated_on fields to be in the concrete class tables, and they are. They just don't show up in the django admin site.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Anoop's answers is partially correct:

```
class BaseModelMixinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('uuid','created_on','updated_on')
```

but then also:

```
admin.site.register(Something, BaseModelMixinAdmin)
admin.site.register(SomethingElse, BaseModelMixinAdmin)
```

... which is a little irritating that I have to do this at all, but oh well, it ain't that bad...

Comment: `editable=False` fields are not shown by default. Consider this http://stackoverflow.com/q/3967644/1925257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to see the non editable fields in admin panel. Use [read only fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) in model admin

```
class BaseModelMixinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields=('uuid',)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Anoop's answer is correct, but to make it more clear, if you're using an abstract model like the `BaseModelMixin` used by @Colin (the OP), your `admin.py` file could look like this:

```py
# admin.py
# ===================================================================
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

# Use this as a mixin to store common logic.
class BaseModelMixinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = (
        'uuid',
        'created_on',
        'updated_on',
    )

# Inherit the mixin.
class SomethingAdmin(BaseModelMixinAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

# Inherit the mixin.
class SomethingElseAdmin(BaseModelMixinAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Something, SomethingAdmin)
admin.site.register(SomethingElse, SomethingElseAdmin)
```

This way, you can still individually modify each admin model and the common logic is inherited from the `BaseModelMixinAdmin`.

Tested using Python 3.8.10 and Django 4.0.