# How to disallow admin to change instance in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model `Order` and model `Invoice`. The `Order` has

```
invoice = models.OneToOneField('Invoice', related_name='order', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Invoice object is created right after order object is created an assigned to it. Admin has to edit the invoice (price field) before customer pays.

The problem is that `Django-admin` allows admin to change this field too (bottom of the image), which I can't risk but I want to let the pencil icon (change attributes of the invoice).

[image]

Is it possible to do that? When I add `invoice` to `readonly_fields` in `OrderAdmin`, Admin can't edit those attributes like invoice.price etc.

EDIT:

So I want admin to be able to edit attributes of the invoice. Not add nor choose from dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to provide a custom template for this view. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_form_template) say that you can specify a path to a custom template using `ModelAdmin.change_form_template`.

Here is a section of the docs that talk about how to override a template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template

Though this is not the optimal solution, you could probably use Javascript to hide/disable the parts you don't want.

Finally, you may want to consider your usage of the Django admin:

> The admin’s recommended use is limited to an organization’s internal
>   management tool. It’s not intended for building your entire front end
>   around.
>
> The admin has many hooks for customization, but beware of trying to
>   use those hooks exclusively. If you need to provide a more
>   process-centric interface that abstracts away the implementation
>   details of database tables and fields, then it’s probably time to
>   write your own views.

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return False
```

[Django admin: How to display a field that is marked as editable=False' in the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967644/django-admin-how-to-display-a-field-that-is-marked-as-editable-false-in-the-mo)

Comment: It has to be editable and only editable. Admin has not to be able to change object or add new. Only edit.

Comment: def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False