# Django: time zone issue

Tags: django, timezone

NOTE: I deleted the question as it existed previously and providing only the relevant info here.

Our database server (RH) has TIME_ZONE = "Europe/London" specified. And, within the Django settings.py, we specify TIME_ZONE = "America/New_York".

And, in my Model class I have specified:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

When I then go look at the data in the admin site, I get UTC/GMT time instead of Eastern.

I thought that all time is adjusted automagically by Django since I specified  "America/New_York" as Django's Time Zone.

Any help/clarification is appreciated.

Thanks
Eric

Comment: what do you get from this ?
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: I just updated the SERVER info. The time Zone is set to On Server Europe/London.

Comment: I rather not use AUTO_NOW. It delegates to database server, which should have time zone set. In this way you lose flexibility to have different time zones by user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Relying on date/time 'automagic' is dangerous and these auto_add model parameters are a trap. Always understand the timezone(s) you are dealing with. Python makes this easier by attaching a tzinfo member to its datetime objects. While these objects are 'naive' by default, I encourage you to always attach tzinfo detail. Still Python needs some extra help with either *python-dateutil* or *pytz* (what I use). Here's a universal rule though - always store your datetimes in a database as UTC.

Why? Your users may be in different locals, mobile phones and laptops travel, servers are misconfigured or mirrored in different timezones. So many headaches. Datetimes should never be naive and if they are (as in a database) and you need the context, also include a timezone field in the table.

So in your case.

1. Don't use the auto_now fields, use a custom save() instead.
2. Store UTC in the database
3. If you need to know the timezone - for say a user event - store the timezone in the database as well.
4. Convert to the necessary/requested timezone

If you are using pytz, the [localize()](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) method is great. Python's datetime object has the useful replace() and astimezone().

One more note, if your database is timezone naive (like MySQL) make sure your datetimes are in UTC and then use replace(tzinfo=None) because the database connector can't handle tz-aware objects.

Here is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add) with detail on Django's auto_now fields.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest/fastest fix [said above by Ajay Yadav] is this ,

Just add TIME_ZONE attribute to the Database's section in settings.py,

**settings.py**

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'TIME_ZONE': 'Asia/Tokyo',
    }
}
```

For the available **Timezone choices** , See the **Official documentation** linked below ,

[DJANGO TIMEZONE CHOICES](https://django-timezone-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/choices.html)

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me much. Here is the documentation for this setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#time-zone

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would want to store my data as UTC cause its a good starting point.

So let me ask this, Why do you need the time in EST, is this for the end-user, or do you need to do logic on the server and need it in EST?

If its for the enduser, an easy fix is to let the users browser handle converting to the correct time. On the server convert the datetime object to a timestamp:

```
timestamp = time.mktime(datetime_obj.timetuple()) * 1000
```

And then on the web page instantiate a Date object:

```
var date_obj = new Date({{ timestamp }});
var datetime_string = date_obj.toString();
// the datetime_string will be in the users local timezone
```

Now, on the other hand, if you want to have the time in the correct zone on the server so you can perform logic on it. I recommend using the help of [python-dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil). It will allow you to easily swap to a different timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import zoneinfo

from_zone = zoneinfo.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = zoneinfo.gettz('America/New_York')

utc = created # your datetime object from the db


# Tell the datetime object that it's in UTC time zone since 
# datetime objects are 'naive' by default
utc = utc.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)

# Convert time zone
eastern_time = utc.aztimezone(to_zone)
```

Now if you really wanna store the datetime in EST, you need change the time on the DB server (like Ajay Yadav and gorus said). I don't know why you want to store them as EST, but then again I don't know what your application is.

Comment: Todd, I guess my question wasn't complete. But I see your points and they are good ones. I am going to use some of your examples in my current project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you say auto_now_add=True, the value will be added by your database server and not your django server. So you need to set time zone on your database server.

Answer (score -1):

Since you edited the question, I'll edit my answer :)  Django cannot control the time zone of your db, so the way to fix this is to update the time zone for your db.  For MySql, run this query:

`SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`

This should return `SYSTEM, SYSTEM` by default, which in your case means "Europe/London", and the cause of your problem.  Now that you've verified this, follow the instructions in the first comment on this page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Remember to restart MySql server after you've updated the time zone for the changes to take effect.

Comment: As long as DB stores timezone offset (don't know about MySQL, but Postgres does this with "timestamp with time zone" data type), Django should not care about DB settings — it should just do the math. Even though Django's considered fairly DB-agnostic, preferably, Eric should specify which DB server he's running (name and version) — that would help debugging.