# Is Django corrupting timezone-aware DateTimeField when saving it to the Database?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, timezone, django-queryset

I have a Django model as described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275987/how-to-write-django-queryset-to-get-unix-timestamp-of-a-datetimefield)

I create and save an instance of this model:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Max, F, Func
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> import pytz, datetime
>>> from myapp.models import myModel

>>> myModel.objects.all().delete()

>>> myModel.objects.create(
    my_date=datetime.datetime(2037,4,2,15,18,17,tzinfo=pytz.UTC), 
    my_string="asda"
)
<myModel: myModel object>
```

Then I try to retrieve the instance I just inserted, but I get the DateTimeField in native format and after applying `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`:

```
>>> x = myModel.objects.values('my_string').aggregate(
    max1=Max('my_date'), 
    max2=Max(Func(F('my_date'), function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP'))
)

>>> x
{
    'max2': Decimal('2122848857.000000'), 
    'max1': datetime.datetime(2037, 4, 8, 20, 14, 17, tzinfo=<UTC>)
}

>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x["max2"])
datetime.datetime(2037, 4, 9, 0, 14, 17)


>>> pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>
>>>
```

If you [convert](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) `2122848857` back to a DateTime, you get `2037-04-09T00:14:17+00:00`. This is 4 hours greater than the time I actually inserted. Why? How to correct this seeming corruption? My machine's timezone is EDT which is 4 hours behind UTC. But that still doesn't explain why Django is saving this UTC time as if it was in my local timezone.

Comment: The `time_zone` setting of the MySQL session will impact values stored and retrieved from `timestamp` and `datetime` columns. To see the current setting of the session: **`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'`** To change the setting (for the current connection only) **`SET time_zone = '+00:00'`**.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805778/django-time-zone-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pytz, datetime
from django.db.models import Max, F, Func
from django.conf import settings
from myapp.models import myModel

local_tz = pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)

local_datetime = local_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2037, 4, 8, 20, 14, 17), is_dst=None)
utc_datetime = local_datetime.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
# datetime.datetime(2037, 4, 9, 0, 14, 17, tzinfo=<UTC>)

MyModel.objects.create(my_date=utc_datetime)

x = MyModel.objects.aggregate(max1=Max('my_date'),max2=Max(Func(F('my_date'), function='UNIX_TIMESTAMP')))

pytz.UTC.localize(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x['max2'])).astimezone(local_tz) == x['max1'].astimezone(local_tz)
```

Comment: But the datetime you entered (2013-12-11-15:18:17) is timezone naive. I need to put in a date that is explicitly UTC. Adding the tzinfo argument to this datetime causes it to fail.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately @madzohan: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/7c1c63a4971223c523e4

Comment: sorry, now it should work (at last I've tested this :D )

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between `datetime` and `timestamp` is that `timestamp` will automatically store a value as UTC, using the current mysql `time_zone` setting, and `datetime` will ignore the `time_zone` setting when inserting and retrieving records.

You're using a `datetime` field, however you're also using the mysql `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function against that field.  When you do that, the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) explain that the server interprets the value as a *local* time value, based on the `time_zone` setting.  This is the source of the conversion discrepancy.

You have two choices.

1. Ensure the `time_zone` session variable is set to UTC before running your query.
2. Store the value into a `timestamp` field instead of a `datetime` field.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Django to answer with the exact code.  This is from a mysql perspective.  According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17442224/634824) you may be able to take advantage of a `USE_TZ` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Some of the data is discarded.

Django DateTime field stored data in a database DateTime storage that lacks timezone information thus the information is removed before storage.

This is whet [the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) says:

> Note that if you set this to point to a DateTimeField, only the date portion of the > field will be considered. Besides, when USE_TZ is True, the check will be performed > in the current time zone at the time the object gets saved.

The proper way to store full datetime date would be to use a DateTimeOffset field - that can be found in MS-Sql and others. But this is not supported ([yet?](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/134))