# Weird behavior of Django's timezone.now()

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am saving the last time a page has been visited, and since I upgraded to Django 1.8, all my dates went wonky... And I really, really dont get it.

I basically have an API that is being poked by kiosk computers set all around the US, but I want to know if at a point in time the kiosk has checked in in the last 3 minutes or not. I don't care in which timezone it is.

I have a simple datetimefield:

```
lastcheckintime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now=False)
```

And when the API is called, I simply save this:

```
monitor.lastcheckintime = timezone.now()
```

With a debug log, looks like it's saving the right UTC time in the database. I'm checkin if a monitor is online with this:

```
@property
def is_online(self):
    if self.lastcheckintime is None:
        return False

    time_threshold = timezone.now() - timedelta(minutes=3)
    return self.lastcheckintime > time_threshold
```

It used to be perfect until I upgraded. I can't tell if it's the upgrade of Django to 1.8 or pytz itself, but now it looks like this:

[image: Last 3 lines are wonky]

(In my timezone it's 10:29pm)

And the weird part is that these lines change ! It's not always the same monitor that's on the wrong time. Also, the whole thing is off by 7 hours (I'm GMT -7). Any other model looks to work correctly, I'm completely lost on why this one is behaving erratically.

Any idea on something I might have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of anything that changed in 1.8 that would cause this. What is the value of `USE_TZ`? The behavior you're seeing kind of looks like you went from using `USE_TZ=True` to `USE_TZ=False`.

Comment: The [`timezone.now()` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2e05ef4e18c8fea0c199e4fc32278cce11158ac0/django/utils/timezone.py#L316) also hints that `settings.USE_TZ` might have changed in your environment.

Comment: My USE_TZ is still set to true. In my case it shouldn't matter in which timezone each device is set to, right? (They should all be in the same one anyways)

Comment: @AlbanDumouilla: it is your responsibility, to make sure that all parts of the system (db, OS, django) use the same timezone e.g., to avoid that utc time is interpreted as a local time and in reverse.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes, they all are. See my answer below, I just recreated the exact same field with a different name and everything works fine. Not sure what happened there, as I don't believe that the field itself could get on a different timezone.

Comment: I am actually wondering if in the end it might be the same issue than this guy has: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303120/is-django-corrupting-timezone-aware-datetimefield-when-saving-it-to-the-database

Answer (score 0):

Still can't understand what happened, but I ended up creating another datetimefield with the exact properties and use this one instead, delete the old lastcheckintime and everything works just fine.

This is still a mystery though... 
Thanks!