# Django DateTimeField auto_now_add not working

Tags: python, django, datetime, model

In one of the model i have set one timestamp field as follows:

```
created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

While in shell i am able to create a obj and save it, however in my application it is raising a exception that created_datetime field cannot be null.

Confused where things went wrong!! How to reslove it.

Comment: Better use a custom `save()` rather than using `auto_now_add`. [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Comment: I don't understand - how and why does that help?

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know, best practice for default datetimes is to use the following:

```
created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Don't forget to import datetime

Comment: is there a similar approach for ``auto_now`` or is it fine as-is?

Comment: I believe best practice for `auto_now` is overriding `save()` and setting the datetime manually.

Comment: As of 2018, this information is outdated. Best practice according to django is to use auto_now=True.

Comment: I had to use `initial=` instead of `default=`

Answer (score 4):

I had this and it really confused me for ages.

Turned out that my model had a custom primary key, and it was due to a bug not setting it when constructing some test objects.

The first time this worked fine as `auto_now_add` set `created_at`. The second time it didn't as the object with a null primary key already existed, so it was doing an update. And it tried to set that to `created_at` null, which wasn't allowed in my model.

So worth checking if you end up on this question with the error "in my application it is raising a exception that created_datetime field cannot be null", that that could be caused by not setting a primary key correctly.

The solution was for me to correctly set a primary key.

Comment: Thanks so much for this comment, it helped me out.  My case was that I was reusing a primary key to make a new record, and django/sqlite for some reason didn't say "you cannot reuse that key", instead it complained about the created_at field.  Your hint here really saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_obj = Organization.objects.get(id=id)
.....
created_at = data_obj.created_at
```

It means call your old saved **created_at** data from database and re-save again during `Updation`
created_at fields not working so save it statically, no need to do dynamically.
My model is `created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Answer (score -2):

The following way is in the "part1" of django documentation

```
from django.utils import timezone
p = Poll(question="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```