# DateTimeField doesn't show in admin system

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

How come my "date" field doesn't come up in the admin system?

In my admin.py file i have

```
from django.contrib import admin
from glasses.players.models import *
admin.site.register(Rating)
```

and the Rating model has a field called "date" which looks like this

```
date = models.DateTimeField(editable=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

However within the admin system, the field doesn't show, even though `editable` is set to `True`.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I believe to reason lies with the `auto_now_add` field.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add/1737078#1737078):

> Any field with the auto_now attribute
>   set will also inherit editable=False
>   and therefore will not show up in the
>   admin panel.

Also mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

> As currently implemented, setting
>   auto_now or auto_now_add to True will
>   cause the field to have editable=False
>   and blank=True set.

This does make sense, since there is no reason to have the field editable if it's going to be overwritten with the current datetime when the object is saved.

Comment: Though surely you should be able to edit `auto_now_add` via the admin *after* the entry has first been created?

Comment: You should also be able to simply *display* it in the admin interface, even if it was uneditable.

Comment: Please refer to the answer by @hunger below for how to display it as a readonly field in the admin interface.

Comment: It does make sense to have a field editable if the field is only inited on an object creation (auto_now_add=True).

Answer (score 262):

If you really want to see date in the admin panel, you can add `readonly_fields` in **admin.py**:

```
class RatingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('date',)

admin.site.register(Rating,RatingAdmin)
```

Any field you specify will be added last after the editable fields. To control the order you can use the `fields` options.

Additional information is available from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields).

Comment: THIS is the real answer!!

Comment: if you stipulate a `fields` you also have to put your field in that, so you would need it both in `readonly_fields` and `fields` otherwise the field wouldn't show up.

Comment: I just wanted to note that this also applied if you are using `fieldsets`, just ran into this issue today.

Comment: This will make the field appear only when we click and open a particular entry. If you want the field to be visible in the listview itself then http://stackoverflow.com/a/34966908/4440874

Comment: Note that I'm not sure why but this does not seem to work for DateTimeFields with `auto_now_add=True` under Django 1.9.  A (sort of) workaround is to add them to the `list_display` tuple instead.  Edit: It will work if you also add your field to `fields` as @BjornTipling mentioned.

Comment: you could also: `admin.site.register(your_model, readonly_fields = ('your_field',))`

Answer (score 25):

*Major Hack:*

If you really need to do this (as I do) you can always hack around it by immediatley setting the field to be "editable" defining the field as follows:

```
class Point(models.Model):
  mystamp=models.DateTimeField("When Created",auto_now_add=True)
  mystamp.editable=True
```

This will make the field editable, so you can actually alter it. It seems to work fine, at least with the mysql backing engine. I cannot say for certian if other backing stores would make this data immutable in the database and thus cause a problem when editing is attempted, *so use with caution*.

Comment: Nah, don't do this, use the readonly_fields solution described by Hunger.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: A rationale would be nice.

Comment: @mhsmith Rationale to use Hunger's solution instead of this: because this is a major hack and comes with "use with caution" , wheras Hunger's solution uses django the way it is designed to be used.   Why would you risk a major hack when you can do what you need in a legitimate and supported fashion?

Comment: This hack solution is not that bad. The only use case for it however I see is testing - when tester need to alter date.

Comment: Or when we migrate the entities from a test server to prod.

Comment: just a warning: this hack messed up the migrations for me

Answer (score 20):

Depending on your specific needs, and any nuances in difference in behavior, you could do the following:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

The default field can be used this way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

```
The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created.
```

This does not set editable to `False`

Comment: I would use `from django.utils.timezone import now` instead of `datetime.now`, but this looks promising.

Comment: Stackoverflow is awesome because, some answers make you realize you didn't ask the right question ! Thank you.

Comment: thanks @orblivion , I have been doing projects in django from so long but wasn't aware of this , thanks again !

Answer (score 6):

If you want any field to be visible in the list of all your entries (when you click on a model in the admin people) and not when you open that particular entry then -

```
class RatingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'date') 

admin.site.register(Rating, RatingAdmin)
```

'name' being your main field or any other field you want to display in the admin panel.

This way you can specify all the columns you want to see.

Answer (score 5):

It might have to do with the auto_now_add being true.  Perhaps instead of that parameter to capture the date on add, you could override the model save method to insert the datetime when the id is null.

```
class Rating(models.Model):

    ....
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if not self.id: 
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: If you did, then there is no reason to define field as __auto_now__

Comment: Not sure why the downvote; the first link Shawn Chin provides indicates a similar approach.

Comment: That's a sensible alternative, assuming `auto_now` is not used and `editable=False`. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Can be displayed in Django admin simply by below code in admin.py**

```
@admin.register(model_name)
class model_nameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['date']
```

Above code will display all fields in django admin that are mentioned in `list_display`, no matter the model field is set to `True` for `auto_now` attribute

Comment: I find this solution with the decorator as the most compact. Alternatively, you define the class and register the model and the class separately.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to create an editable time field that defaults to the current time.

I actually found that the best option was to avoid the `auto_now` or `auto_add_now` altogether and simply use the datetime library.

```
MyTimeField = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

The big thing is that you should make it's the variable `now` instead of a function/getter, otherwise you're going to get a new default value each time you call `makemigrations`, which will result in generating a bunch of redundant migrations.

Comment: This is a much more accurate resolution to the issue at hand. It properly provides a way to make the field visible and properly editable at the admin site, while maintaining the correct behavior on the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

**auto_now** and **auto_now_add** are all **non-editable** fields and you can not override them...

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of the answers by *Hunger* and using a decorator as suggested by *Rahul Kumar*:

In your admin.py, you just need:

```
@admin.register(Rating)
class RatingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('date',)
```

The fields specified in `readonly_fields` will appear in the add and change page i.e. inside the individual record. And - of course - are not editable.

The fields in `list_display` will constitute the representation in the main list page of the admin (i.e. the list of all records). In this case, it makes sense not to specify `list_display = ('date',)` only, because you will see only the dates. Instead, include also the main title / name of the record.

Example:

```
readonly_fields = ('title', 'date',)
```

if in the models.py this model is defined as:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Movie Title', max_length=150)
    ...
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=True, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```