# admin panel, show date_created and date_updated?

Tags: django

I tried following an answer at this previous post:
[DateTimeField doesn't show in admin system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386172/datetimefield-doesnt-show-in-admin-system)

But maybe I'm just too dim to understand it.

No field of created_at shows up. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

model

```
class holding_transaction(models.Model):
    holdingname = models.ForeignKey(holding, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

admin.py

```
class holding_transactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ('created_at', )

admin.site.register(holding_transaction, holding_transactionAdmin)
```

Edit:

Comment: did you try adding it to `list_display`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update:

Here is the code that worked for me for an imaginary application called `Beatles`:

beatles/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

beatles/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from beatles.models import Person


@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('created_at', )
```

---

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6386240/2996101) to the question mentioned, states that this is not possible to happen.

Nonetheless, if you want to edit such fields, according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) you proceed as follows:

> If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead
>   of auto_now_add=True:
>
> ```
> For DateField: default=date.today - from datetime.date.today()
> For DateTimeField: default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now()
> ```

If you want those fields just to be displayed, you can use the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660030/2996101):

> ```
> class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     readonly_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at', )
>
> admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
> ```

Comment: I just want them to be displayed. I tried your 2nd block, but was not succesful, are there anything else I need to do to apply it?

Comment: You also need to add a fields option to PersonAdmin like so: fields = ('name', 'created_at') The readonly_fields option only makes specified fields read-only, it does not add them.