# model_to_dict is not returning DateTimeField with auto_now_add = True

Tags: django, datetime, models

I have created a model as:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    jobId = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    startTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

When I'm doing

```
print(model_to_dict(job))
```

I'm getting only

```
{'jobId': 1}
```

as output. Why 'startTime' filed is not coming in the output? Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A: `model_to_dict` is only outputting editable fields.

B: `startTime` is [not set editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386172/datetimefield-doesnt-show-in-admin-system) because of the `auto_now_add`.

So I guess you end up with one of the methods from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact) question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found one solution from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22015427/4608329) answer.