# New model field showing in database query but not in django admin

Tags: python, django

I just added `time_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` to my Shift model and when I query an object in the database it shows `'time_inserted': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 5, 15, 26, 20, 226797)` great! But I don't see it as a field in admin, how can I get it to appear there?

Comment: Fields with `auto_now_add` don't show in the admin, because you shouldn't change them. You can add them to `readonly_fields` though.

Comment: Do you mean add it to a `readonly` field as opposed to `DateTimeField`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTimeField doesn't show in admin system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386172/datetimefield-doesnt-show-in-admin-system)

Comment: No, I mean adding your `time_inserted` field to the [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) tuple in the ModelAdmin class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you set `auto_now_add` you implicitly set the `readonly` property, which means it won't by default show up in Django's model admin.

However, if you would just like to see the *value* of it; without changing it, you can do it with a custom ModelAdmin class:

```
class RatingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('time_inserted',)

admin.site.register(Rating,RatingAdmin)
```