# Is DateTimeField with auto_now_add option enabled must has value in fixtures

Tags: django, django-models, django-fixtures

I have model created field configurated as follows:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In JSON fixtures I don't want to declare value for created, but when I try to load fixtures (loadata) I am getting error:

> created may not be NULL

So I must provide created value in fixtures or there is an other way?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try

```
import datetime
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

And about why this happening you can read over here: [Django auto_now and auto_now_add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add) and [Django model field default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default)

Comment: This is a bad suggestion.  datetime.datetime.now() will be evaluated when the models are loaded.  The default datetime for this created field will be when the server was last started, basically.

Edit: Here's what oburejin actually wanted.
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

(Default takes a callable object, for calling at actual instantiation time.  See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default)

Comment: For reference, it is better to use django.utils's timezone function since it handles timezone. Otherwise you'll get a warning. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Answer (score 3):

You can use pre_save signal to process loaddata(fixtures)

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def pre_save_for_conference_code_fixture(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  if kwargs['raw']:
    instance.updated_at = timezone.now()
      if not instance.id:
        instance.created_at = timezone.now()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata