# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: django, django-mailer

I m trying to send a simple mail using IPython. I have not set up any models still getting this error. What can be done?

> Error :
>   /home/sourabh/Django/learn/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:827: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-09-04 14:14:13.698105) while time zone support is active.
>     RuntimeWarning)

Tried : The first step is to add `USE_TZ = True` to your settings file and install `pytz` (if possible).

Error changed:

```
(learn)sourabh@sL:~/Django/learn/event$ python manage.py shell
/home/sourabh/Django/learn/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:53: RuntimeWarning: SQLite received a naive datetime (2013-09-05 00:59:32.181872) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Answer (score 724, accepted):

The problem is not in Django settings, but in the **date** passed to the model. Here's how a timezone-aware object looks like:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> import pytz
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 20, 8, 7, 127325, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

And here's a naive object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 20, 9, 26, 423063)
```

So if you are passing email date anywhere (and it eventually gets to some model), just use Django's `now()`. If not, then it's probably an issue with an existing package that fetches date without timezone and you can patch the package, ignore the warning or set USE_TZ to False.

Comment: Where you write `tzinfo=<UTC>`, what is `<UTC>`? That is not a syntactic construct I have seen.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but what you are seeing is **output** from the shell. More specifically, it's the output from the datetime object's __repr__ method, that returns printable information of the object.

Comment: In places where you were using `datetime.now`, change it to `timezone.now`, and add `from django.utils import timezone` at the top.

Comment: For those still looking for that <UTC> part, you can use this:
`import pytz`
 `datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 20, 20, 8, 7, 127325, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)`

Comment: My settings are `USE_TZ = True`, `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`. But when I use `timezone.now()` it doesn't show `tzinfo=<UTC>`.... So this datetime object is passed as naive one. Why does it happen?

Comment: `In [3]: timezone.datetime.strptime("2017-01-01 23:11:11", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 23, 11, 11)`

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to parse datetime string from frontend simillar to @user3595632 using `timezone.datetime.strptime`. the result is correct as expected, but I stil got naive object warning.

Comment: @Anoyz the Django docs seem to suggest that doing that is not recommended? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Answer (score 214):

Use [django.utils.timezone.make_aware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) function to make your naive datetime objects timezone aware and avoid those warnings.

It converts naive datetime object (without timezone info) to the one that has timezone info (using timezone specified in your django settings if you don't specify it explicitly as a second argument):

```
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

naive_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
naive_datetime.tzinfo  # None

settings.TIME_ZONE  # 'UTC'
aware_datetime = make_aware(naive_datetime)
aware_datetime.tzinfo  # <UTC>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's the most django-compliant way to transform naive dates into dates with the timezone of my django settings :)

Comment: Is it possible to put this in models.py?

Comment: @Florent there is no need to change anything in models if you use utc timezone by default, `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` will work fine for datetime fields. If you need to have timezone aware current datetime object in models for some reason - use `django.utils.timezone.now()` function.

Comment: What if one is using it in models like ` created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)` ? How should it be done here?

Answer (score 68):

Just to fix the error to set current time

```
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) # you can use this value
```

Comment: and for datetime.datetime(9999, 01, 01, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

Comment: IMO this is the most practical solution

Comment: from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now() #will also work

Answer (score 25):

Quick and dirty - Turn it off:

```
USE_TZ = False
```

in your `settings.py`

Comment: When USE_TZ is True and the database supports time zones (e.g. PostgreSQL), it is an error to set this option

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#time-zone

Answer (score 25):

make sure settings.py has
`USE_TZ = True`

In your python file:

```
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.now() # use its value in model field
```

Answer (score 18):

One can both fix the warning *and* use the timezone specified in settings.py, which might be different from UTC.

For example in my settings.py I have:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
```

Here is a solution; the advantage is that `str(mydate)` gives the correct time:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone
>>> mydate = datetime.now(tz=get_current_timezone())
>>> mydate
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 10, 11, 16, 9, 184106, 
    tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
>>> str(mydate)
'2019-03-10 11:16:09.184106+01:00'
```

Another equivalent method is using `make_aware`, see dmrz post.

Comment: i just followed your idea above and used an effective timezone string in my test.py. It worked flawless and i feel is even better than modifying setting.py just for this purpose.

Answer (score 14):

If you are trying to transform a naive datetime into a datetime with timezone in django, here is my solution:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-07-16 22:24:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> t1
    datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 16, 22, 24)
>>> current_tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
>>> t2 = current_tz.localize(t1)
>>> t2
    datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 16, 22, 24, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' CST+8:00:00 STD>)
>>>
```

t1 is a naive datetime and t2 is a datetime with timezone in django's settings.

Answer (score 14):

You can also override settings, particularly useful in tests:

```
from django.test import override_settings

with override_settings(USE_TZ=False):
    # Insert your code that causes the warning here
    pass
```

This will prevent you from seeing the warning, at the same time anything in your code that requires a timezone aware datetime may give you problems. If this is the case, see kravietz answer.

Answer (score 8):

In the model, do not pass the value:

```
timezone.now()
```

Rather, remove the parenthesis, and pass:

```
timezone.now
```

If you continue to get a runtime error warning, consider changing the model field from DateTimeField to DateField.

Answer (score 1):

I use function to covert `date` -> `datetime` aware format like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from django.utils import timezone

def date_to_datetime_aware(d:date) -> datetime:
    dt = datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time())
    dt_aware = timezone.make_aware(dt)
    return dt_aware
```

It helps me to awoid Django RuntimeWarning.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert the actual date string to date object, I have got rid of the warning by simply using `astimezone`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime_str = '2013-09-04 14:14:13.698105'
>>> datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> datetime_object.astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 4, 6, 14, 13, 698105, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this warning when using the following model.

```
from datetime import datetime

class MyObject(models.Model):
    my_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

To fix it, I switched to the following default.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class MyObject(models.Model):
    my_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: type object 'datetime.timezone' has no attribute 'now'

Comment: Type object `datetime.timezone` has not indeed, but my solution is referring to `django.utils.timezone` which has the `now` attribute.