# suppress django naive datetime warnings

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am concerned with a script that involves datetime module. I have to suppress 'object received a naive datetime while timezone is active' as there are other print statements in the script. My code is as below

script:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()

objName = className.objects.create(param=value, param=value, param=value, time=date, attachment=attachment)
```

models.py

```
class className(models.MOdel):
    t = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I suppress naive datetime warnings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to suppress(which is not a good idea though) warning messages, use just these two lines

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
```

To suppress all types of warnings, don't provide a specific `Warning` class.

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score -3):

Just disable the usage of timezones, as [stated in the documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ)

```
USE_TZ = False
```

Comment: Its already set to false. Is there a way to suppress the error messages? I mean I dont want them to appear in the terminal.