# Django: Default datetime value is causing noisy tests

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I added a field to one of my models:

```
date_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I ran `manage.py migrate` it asked for a default. I could not add a default to the models as `default` is mutually exclusive of `auto_now=True`. It wouldn't allow me.

So I punched in a quick default string: `"12-12-2015"` and went on my way.

However, every time I run my tests I get an ugly error:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField BusinessAccount.date_created received a naive datetime (2015-09-13 02:14:32.898795) while time zone support is active.
```

I've changed the models in response:

```
date_created= models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

But the error remains. I tried squashing the migration where I added the original value, but it didn't seem to do anything.

EDIT: Looking closer at the output, it seems that `datetime.now` is submitting a string instead of a datetime object and is now causing the same problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: A similar problem is discussed (and solved) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime

Comment: Thanks, but using `now()` as a function would cause problems in this case.

Comment: I don't want the function to occur everytime the field is queried. Only the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to store the creation time use auto_now_add=True

```
date_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: This produces the same "naive datetime" complaint.