# django : how to save DateTimeField

Tags: django, datetime, save

I have a python function that reads data from a javascript file :

```
def eventsdrag(request):

try:
    
    try:
        untitre = request.GET.get('title')
       
    except:
        untitre = None
try:
        debut = float(request.GET.get('start'))
        debut = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(debut)
except:
        debut = None
 try:
        lafin = float(request.GET.get('end'))
        lafin = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(lafin)
except:
        lafin = None
```

I display:

> debut 2016-02-09 00:00:00
>
> lafin 2016-02-16 00:00:00

I want to save `debut` and `lafin` in the database.

My model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_(u"Nom de l'étude"), max_length=100)
    start = models.DateTimeField(_(u"début"))
    end = models.DateTimeField(_('fin'))
    ...
```

If I write in the function

```
try:
    p = Event(title= untitre, start=debut, end=lafin)
    p.save(force_insert=True)
```

I have the error :

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2016-02-16 00:00:00) while time zone support is active

Is it the solution to write ? :

```
debut = debut.astimezone(timezone.get_default_timezone())
lafin = lafin.astimezone(timezone.get_default_timezone())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Comment: Please choose a more relevant title for your question.

Comment: how to save start and end ?

Comment: Try use: `debut = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(debut)`, `lafin = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(lafin)`

Comment: it is the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the datetime class from django.utils.timezone instead of the native datetime. Or you may disable the timezone in your settings. (here is the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: I put  TIME_ZONE = None in the setting file and no change

Comment: tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris")
debut = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(debut, tz) but i can not save debut with p = Event(debut..) and p.save() what is the problem with pytz ?