# received a naive datetime while time zone support is active

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to insert some records to a Django Model which include some old dates in unix ctime Format. I am comverting it to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss and saving it to a model in datetime field.

While running a import job ( Function which is converting the unix dates to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) and saving it , I am getting a warning below

```
C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField SensorRecords.aqdate received a naive datetime (2012-07-06 05:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

How should I import it so to avoid this ?

This is my Converter Function

```
def ctodatetime (ctimeinput):
    etime=time.ctime(int(ctimeinput))
    btime=datetime.datetime.strptime(etime,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    print(btime)
    return btime
```

Here is a snippet of my model

```
class SensorRecords(models.Model):
    sensorid  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    aqdate    = models.DateTimeField(default= "1970-01-01 00:00:00")
    cmpflaf   = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add **`tz_info`** to the `datetime` object before passing to the model instance.

```
import pytz
import datetime
import time
from django.conf import settings


def ctodatetime(ctimeinput):
    etime = time.ctime(int(ctimeinput))
    btime = datetime.datetime.strptime(etime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    tz_aware_datetetime = btime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))
    print(tz_aware_datetetime)
    return tz_aware_datetetime
```

The **`.replace()`** function returns a **new datetime object**
For more info, refer this SO post [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Comment: Thanks for the Help @jpg , but its Still showing same Warning and the printed Date in same Format. I will read the link you sent.

Answer (score 1):

A Django-specific solution could be using `django.utils.timezone`, in the following manner:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

def ctodatetime(ctimeinput):
    etime = time.ctime(int(ctimeinput))
    btime = datetime.strptime(etime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    tz = getattr(settings, 'TIME_ZONE', None)
    return timezone.make_aware(btime, tz)
```

This relies on the fact that `btime` will be a naive timestamp, and makes use of Django’s [make_aware()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) to convert it to a timezone-aware timestamp.