# Django RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I'm dockerizing my Django application. Since I changed my database from SQLite to Postgres the migration fails and I get this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Posts.created_at received a naive datetime (2020-01-19 14:26:30.893128) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp with time zone
LINE 1: ..." TYPE timestamp with time zone USING "created_at"::timestam...
```

I have searched the other issues and tried this fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106079/7400518 
I was using `datetime.now()` then I changed it to `timezone.now()` but I'm still getting the same error.
This is the related lines from `models.py`

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Posts(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), blank=True)
```

Comment: Remove the migration file where it still uses the old `datetime`. Furthermore you should use `auto_now_add`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was using `datetime.now()` then I changed it to `timezone.now()` but I'm still getting the same error.

Changing the model will *not* change the migration file. You should look up what migration files contain `datetime.now()`, and remove this (together with all the other migrations that depend on that).

Furthermore using `default=timezone.now()` is *not* a good idea. It will use as default the time when you *start* the webserver. That thus means that if the server runs for two days, the timestamp will still use the timestamp of two days ago.

The `DateTimeField` has however an [**`auto_now_add=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to automatically use the timestamp when you add the object:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This will set the field to `blank=True`, and `editable=False` as well.