# Django DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active

Tags: django, django-i18n, django-timezone

I'm using **Django 2.2**

In my application, timezone support is enabled by **USE_TZ=True** in the settings file.

I have models with **DateTime** field `created`.

I need to filter data based on the date. The date can be provided by the user or else it will be default to `now()`.

This is what I'm doing

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

class Generator:

    def __init__(self, start_date=None, end_date=None):

        if end_date:
            self.end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        else:
            self.end_date = timezone.now().date()

        if start_date:
            self.start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        else:
            self.start_date = self.end_date - timedelta(days=7)

    def get_query(self, d):

        query = MyModel.objects.filter(
            d__in=d,
            created__gte=start_date,
            created__lte=end_date
        )

        return query
```

But this is giving error

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField MyModel.created received a naive datetime (2020-02-28 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
```

**How can I get this issue solved?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When time zone support is enabled, the database layer expects to receive only aware datetimes from your code. This warning occurs when it receives a naive datetime. This indicates that you haven’t finished porting your code for time zone support. check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting).

You need to change naive datetime to your project timezone datetime by using [`make_aware()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware) function. For that you have to update your code like below.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

class Generator:

    def get_mytimezone_date(original_datetime):
        new_datetime = datetime.strptime(original_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')
        tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
        timzone_datetime = timezone.make_aware(new_datetime, tz, True)
        return timzone_datetime.date()

    def __init__(self, start_date=None, end_date=None):

        if end_date:
            self.end_date = self.get_mytimezone_date(end_date)
        else:
            self.end_date = timezone.now().date()

        if start_date:
            self.start_date = self.get_mytimezone_date(start_date)
        else:
            self.start_date = self.end_date - timedelta(days=7)

    def get_query(self, d):

        query = MyModel.objects.filter(
            d__in=d,
            created__gte=start_date,
            created__lte=end_date
        )

        return query
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following code to ensure the start_date and end_date having timezone info. 
E.g.

```
tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()

start_date = start_date.replace(tzinfo=tz)
end_date = end_date.replace(tzinfo=tz)
```

Answer (score -1):

To not get a naive datetime, if `myday` is a string representing a date, convert it directly to a date this way:

```
from time import strptime

myday = date(*strptime(myday, "%Y-%m-%d")[:3])
```

This method avoids having to translate from naive to aware datetime.