# Filtering wrong using a timestamp range in django views

Tags: python, django, django-views, timestamp

When I want to filter my model using one exactly date I use the following code line,

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
today_data = DevData.objects.filter(data_timestamp__date=today)
```

And when I want to filter using a range of days, I use the following code line,

```
last7days = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
last7days_data = DevData.objects.filter(data_timestamp__range=(last7days,today))
```

The problem is that when I use this second code, appears a warning and runs very very slow,

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField DevData.data_timestamp received a naive datetime (2020-05-31 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.

How can I do it better?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime), but don't understand how to solve it. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it runs rather slow is likely because you did not set a database index on the `data_timestamp` field, you can add one by specifying a [**`db_index=True`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db_index):

```
class DevData(models.Data):
    data_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    # …
```

You can furthermore filter the data by adding a [**`__date`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date) in the query:

```
last7days = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
last7days_data = DevData.objects.filter(
    data_timestamp__date__range=(last7days,today)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a warning because `last7days` variable is not timezone-aware.

You can make it timezone-aware like so:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timezone

unaware = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
aware = unaware.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc))
```