# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active

Tags: django, django-views, python-datetime

Here I am writing a middleware to delete objects older than 3 months. The `date_before_2_month` and `datetime_before_2_months` is working fine. I haven't tested yet for filtering But in my console it is giving me a runtime warning saying `activity_time` received a naive datetime.

Is this warning a issue(*needs to solve*) or *we can ignore it* ?

Also does my filter parameters are good for querying the objects from model which are 2 months old ?

`activity_time` in model is `DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

```
class UserActivityLogDeleteMiddleware(object):  # middleware for deleting user activity logs which are older than 2 months

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        date_before_2_month = datetime.date.today() - relativedelta(months=2) 
        # converting into datetime
        datetime_before_2_month = datetime.datetime.combine(date_before_2_month, datetime.time(9, 00, 00))
        # deleting logs older than 2 months
        UserActivityLog.objects.filter(activity_time__lt=datetime_before_2_month).delete()

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: You deletion query looks good to me, regarding the naive datetime check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you want to keep your datetimes timezone aware if you're using timezones through your app.

There are a couple of improvements I can see to your code. When using relativedelta you can set the hour and minute to make life a bit easier.

```
from django.utils import timezone

...

def __call__(self, request):
    # Getting a datetime for 2 months ago at 9am
    dt_2_months_ago = timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=2, hour=9, minute=0) 

    # deleting logs older than 2 months
    UserActivityLog.objects.filter(activity_time__lt=dt_2_months_ago).delete()

    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

One note here, are you sure you want to be running this in middleware? It'll run on every single request, every time you get js, every ajax request etc. Just a thought.

Comment: I don't want the user to go to some specific view to delete the activity log so I write it in middleware.Is there any approach for this besides middleware ?

Comment: Couple of ways to do it. The best way would be to have a CronJob that runs periodically, every three hours for instance.

Or overwrite the save method of your UserActivityLog model.