# Delete django data without RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: python, django, utc

I am trying to delete 3 years old data in my python django db. Here is code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def db_cleanup():
    cleanup_start = datetime.utcnow().date()
    three_years_ago = cleanup_start - relativedelta(years=3)

    MyData.objects.filter(create_date__lt=three_years_ago).delete()
```

however I receive RuntimeWarning: **DateTimeField received a naive datetime** . How to do it properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `timezone.now()` to create an aware datetime then reset time to midnight but keep a datetime object (not date):

```
from django.utils import timezone
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def db_cleanup():
    cleanup_start = timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    three_years_ago = cleanup_start - relativedelta(years=3)

    MyData.objects.filter(create_date__lt=three_years_ago).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks. I take it as workaround. The code gets rid of warning, but reaching UTC date by cutting off hours, ... why do I need to cut them at all? For this 3 years range I could live with just timezone.now(). I still hope to get some good solution for other places where I need e.g. 8h ago data.

Comment: I cut time because you use a date and not a datetime. You can just use `three_years_ago = timezone.now() - relativedelta(years=3)`