# Django translation. RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

English is the default language of the project. When I switch language, values of all date fields are disrepair. When I try to fill up the form and send it, appear this error: `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2022-11-27 12:00:00.045143) while time zone support is active.`

[image: datafield become like this]

[image]

I think the problem with time zone. if make this `USE_TZ = False` the translation is not working at all...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622007/runtimewarning-datetimefield-received-a-naive-datetime)