# Django can't auto save DateTimeFields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi I have a model like so:

```
from datetime import datetime


class Project(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey('tool.product')
    module = models.ForeignKey('tool.module')
    model = models.ForeignKey('tool.model')
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.now()
        self.updated = datetime.now()
        super(Project, self).save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

However when I try to save a project I get:

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

and from the runserver:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2012-10-31 14:45:36.611622) while time zone support is active.
```

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is here but I'm assuming it has something to do with `timezone` getting in the way of saving the `DateTimeField`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm just wondering... is there any reason why you are not using auto_now and auto_now_add available for [DateField and DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Comment: I read that it was not a very good implementation: http://www.benspaulding.us/weblog/2008/aug/02/auto_now_add-evil/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all DateTimeField supports auto updating like this:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True) # Only on creation
updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True)     # On every save
```

Secondly the RuntimeWarning you get, means that you have enabled in your
settings.py timezone aware datetime objects e.g you will see the following:

```
USE_TZ = True
```

When you do that, you have to treat datetime objects differently, you have to pass
explicitly a `tzinfo` value.

```
# install the `pytz` module through pip or whatnot
from pytz import timezone
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)

# To show the time in Greece
athens = timezone('Europe/Athens')
print now.astimezone(athens)
```

For more info see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) and the [pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

About the `coercing to Unicode:` error, try doing this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.id)
```

Comment: Is there some way to enable TZ as well as auto saving?

Comment: Or is there a problem if I have TZ disabled?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you look at your settings.py then USE_TZ will be True. But when you do your thing with the datetime objects, you don't use timezones. That's why django is nagging you.

Comment: @DarwinTech It depends on what you want to do. I always use timezone aware dates. I ll update my post.

Comment: So I changed the model to `auto_save` but I am still getting the unicode error.

Comment: @DarwinTech Look at the bottom of the answer. I just updated.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to store `now` on creation, was use the `default` attribute of the DateTimeField, and [Django's now() wrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) like so:

```
from django.utils import timezone

ctime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Please note that this date is in UTC timezone, if you require some other time zone to be set, wrap `timezone.now` in a lambda that calls [localtime()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime)