# Colum not showing in admin panel

Tags: python, django

Implementing custom user for my project,
here is my `account/models.py`

```
class myUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    #blah
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #blah
```

and my `account/admin.py`

```
class myUserDetail(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email','password','is_active','is_staff','date_joined',)
    fields = list_display    

admin.site.register(myUser, myUserDetail)
```

The list_display works fine, but when I click into a user,
error is raised :
    `Unknown field(s) (date_joined) specified for myUser. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class myUserDetail.`

In fact it exists in postgres...
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being triggered when the `ModelForm` is created automatically for the admin, specifically [if there are missing fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3226050358cfcffcb14f7e48e3a5cee873388406/django/forms/models.py#L297-L301). Because you are using `auto_now_add=True`, [which implicitly sets `editable=False`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1737017/359284), the field cannot be included in the automatically generated form. Because of this, an error is triggered.

I would recommend specifying `fields` and `list_display` independently, as they aren't actually the same.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. But can I explicitly specify `date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True)`

Comment: @taesu Even if Django doesn't trigger an error, [it wouldn't have any effect](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3226050358cfcffcb14f7e48e3a5cee873388406/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1181).

Comment: thanks. you not only answered me the question, but taught me to search these within the project itself.

Answer (score -1):

When you use a custom User model in Django you should add the following line to your settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
```

I also think you should subclass from `AbstractUser` which is an abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with admin-compliant permissions, and includes `email`, `date_joined`, etc. fields.

You can read more about customizing the user model [in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: I have set the AUTH_USER_MODEL , and my choice of AbstractBaseUser over AbstractUser is intentional. Im sorry but this does not answer my question.

Comment: which part of the code do you require to see? I thought I've supplied enough block of code.. hm..