# Django - Time since model created

Tags: python, django, datetime, timedelta

How du you calculate the time since a model was created? The model has the following field:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is what I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@property
def time_since_created(self):
    return (datetime.now()-self.created_at).total_seconds()
```

What I do not understand is that it crashes without giving me any error messages. If I wrap it in a try/except block like this:

```
@property
    def time_since_created(self):
        try:
            return (datetime.now()-self.created_at).total_seconds()
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                print("Error:" + e)
            except:
                print("Error: An exception occured when trying to print exception")
```

The error I will get is `"Error: An exception occured when trying to print exception"`. If I do not include the last try/catch block I won't get any output at all.

Do anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what did not work? error message? wrong result?

Comment: is `time_since_created` a method inside the model's class? I see only the function but no class so I am not sure

Comment: Yes it is, I use it in a serializer class in django rest framework.

Comment: Try `print(e)` or `print('Error': + str(e))` see what message you get from the first exception (if you're going to concatenate the string I think you need to convert `str(e)`)

Comment: Are you using `USE_TZ` setting in your project? What is its value?

Comment: @bakkal I tried changing it, still no difference.

Comment: @bellum My USE_TZ is set to true

Comment: Yes but what is the error? You should be able to read the exception message

Comment: @bakkal I finally got an error message. It said Error:can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: @ValdemarEdvardSandalRolfsen then read my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to do the same actions by myself and I have got error:

```
can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

It's because `datetime.now()` is naive and `self.created_at` is aware time. So try to use `timezone.now()` instead:

```
from django.utils import timezone

@property
def time_since_created(self):
    return (timezone.now()-self.created_at).total_seconds()
```

Comment: I'm adding dateTime to `time_since_created(dateTime)`. But it gives me this error: **'property' object is not callable**

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**: re-post for django solution

After checking previous stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add) and some other post. They suggest not to using the `auto_now_add`, but add `default` argument as format.

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

I think it might be the format problem, and this should solve that.
And sorry for my previous answer.

**Edit**:
after checking the django source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/11932e978f980846d2c3326ff070ece7e65bf75c/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2116), the `auto_now_add` arg appear to apply

```
value = datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

to model instance.

And in my test, if I "minus" this value with `datetime.now().time()`, it pops

```
TypeError: unsupported operaand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'
```

But I'm not sure about your django version, maybe the source code has been modified.

Comment: didn't notice this is a django question, my apologies.