# Django auto_now and auto_now add not working, saves None

Tags: python, django

I have a django model DateTimeField with auto_now=True and auto_now_add=True for created and updated. When I save the model, both fields saves as None. Anyone know what's causing this?

The model:

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    ..
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ..
```

It has custom save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #TODO: fix the created and updated field that is not working now
        if not self.id:
            code_settled = False
            while not code_settled:
                referral_code = self._generate_referral_code()
                try:
                    r = Referral.objects.get(referral_code=referral_code)
                except:
                    self.referral_code = referral_code
                    code_settled = True

            self.expiry_date = self.reward_program.expiry_date
            if self.referrer.user.profile.cellphone_verified:
                self.referrer_reward_status = 'F'
            else:
                self.referrer_reward_status = 'C'

            if self.referee.profile.cellphone_verified:
                self.referee_reward_status = 'F'
            else:
                self.referee_reward_status = 'C'
        else:
            self._referral_code = self.referral_code

        super(Referral, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How I create the Referral:

```
referral = Referral(referrer=referrer, referee=user, reward_program=self, _referral_code='stub')
referral.save()
```

auto_now works in my other models in my code base.
I tried commenting out the custom save method to see if it's causing the problem, but apparently it's not. I know there are alternative solutions already to fix this, but I am very curious what is causing this inconsistency.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add

Comment: @GThamizh appreciate the reply, but I have seen this link already. I see so far no one can explain this phenomenon yet :)

Comment: Make a BaseModel class and add these(datetime) fields in it. And inherit BaseModel in your own Models, for BaseModel class make a Meta Class and `abstract = True` for BaseModel class.

Comment: update to the problem: I tried implementing the solution mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add, but turns out it doesn't work as well, i.e. when I see my mySQL DB, I can see something like: 2016-03-10 05:26:33.000000 on the updated DateTimeField, but in django admin and front-end, it still shows as None