# How to update last_changed field on many2many update in Django

Tags: django, model

Imagine I have the two models `Pizza` and `Topping` and the `Pizza` model has a `last_changed` field with `auto_now=True` and a `ManyToMany` relationship to `Topping`.

I now want the `last_changed` field to be updated whenever I add another `Topping` to the `Pizza`. Unfortunately this is not updated automatically since the `Pizza` model does not get saved in such a case. This is because the `ManyToMany` relationship is held in a separate (auto created) model and table.

So what would be the best approach to update the `last_changed` field?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method on your `Pizza` model that gets called whenever you add a `Topping` to it.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField('Toppings', related_name="pizzas")
    last_changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    # Your other fields here

    def add_topping(self, topping):
        self.toppings.add(topping)
        self.save()  # Which would update last_changed
```

But I would also recommend against the use of `auto_now` ([see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add)).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your suggestion. I just wonder how to enforce that everyone calls the add_topping method. If I have to enforce this, I could directly enforce everyone to just call the save().

Comment: @Fabian: how do you mean enforce? Do you not write the code? Sorry if I don't understand