# Django auto_now behaviour

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class MetaData(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated_by')
```

The update_at field is also completed with a value at the creation time instead of being null. I expected to have a value, only after the first save/creation.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Django, you have [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) both.

From the docs:

> #### `DateField.auto_now`

> Automatically set the field to now *every time the object is saved.* (which means when it is first created too)

> #### `DateField.auto_now_add`

> Automatically set the field to now *when the object is first created*.

***Edit***:

If you want your `updated_at` field to be `null` when the object is first created, you can simply pass `null=True` alongside with `auto_now=True` to the `DateTimeField`:

```
class MetaData(models.Model):
    # ...
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    # ...
```

Comment: There is any solution to overwrite the behavior ?

Comment: @user3541631 I've just edited my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: @user3541631 better have a look at this about use of auto_now and auto_now_add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add

Comment: @wencakisa Are you sure that "auto_now=True, null=True" will work? Just tested it on Postgres DB and it doesn't. Also I don't see how that implementation would be possible on Postgress

Comment: @zoran, as you already noted, I also confirm that `updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)` does **not(!)** work. it is set every time the object is saved (including when record is created). note: tested with django 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way to do that. It is better to do what wencakisa recommended, unless you are using `save` method within your model.

As it is written in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)

> The field is only **automatically updated when calling Model.save()**. The
>   field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways
>   such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for
>   the field in an update like that.

So, even if you use `auto_now`, but call `save` method for example to generate a slug address, the time will be assigned to the field with `auto_now` when the object is created.

How to handle such situation and keep the field `updated_at` with a `null` value after creation and before update?

For example, if you are using an UpdateView, assign the time there in a `form_valid` method.

**models.py**

```
class MetaData(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated_by')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # SOMETHING HERE
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class UpdateMetaData(generic.UpdateView):
    # SOMETHING HERE

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.updated_at = timezone.now()
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You should have `null` value for `updated_at` after creation and the right time value after update of the field.

I think that in the same way you can also assign the update author to `updated_by`.