# Why DateTimeField with auto_now_add can not get in form fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Following is my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(_('Code'), max_length=56, null=False,
                        blank=False, db_column='code')
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=128, null=False,
                        db_index=True, db_column='name', blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Created At'), null=False,
                                      db_column='created_at', blank=False,
                                      auto_now_add=True)
```

Form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel 
        fields = '__all__'
```

view

```
class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = MyForm(request=request)
        return render(request, 'test_manager/testrule_form.html', {'form': form})
```

When I display this form, I am able to see all fields excluding created_at.
Does anyone know how do I get created_at field while updating certain object?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737078/67579

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specify `auto_now=True`, or `auto_now_add=True`, then you make the field `editable=False` at the same time. Hence it means it will not show up in the form.

Probably a minimal change would be to specify a `default` value by using a function, instead of using the `auto_now_add=True` property, like:

```
from django.utils import timezone as tz

class TestRule(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(_('Code'), max_length=56, null=False,
                        blank=False, db_column='code')
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=128, null=False,
                        db_index=True, db_column='name', blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Created At'), null=False,
                                      db_column='created_at', blank=False,
                                      default=tz.now)
```

Note that we do *not* call the `now(..)` function. If we would do that, then we would set the `created_at` column to the timestamp when we constructed the *models* (not the instances of the model). By passing a reference to the `now(..)` function, the function will be called when a new model instance is added.

Comment: Hint: the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) suggest using `from django.utils import timezone as tz` and then `tz.now` instead of `datetime.now`. I don't know why they didn't change all of their examples yet in the official docs.

Comment: @DikshaJiwane: well that is in the answer: setting a `default=tz.now`. `auto_now` actually has more implications: it makes the field not editable.

Comment: @DikshaJiwane: ah, you mean `auto_now` (instead of `auto_now_add`)?

Comment: @DikshaJiwane: for `auto_now_add` we can use this `default=...` approach. But for `default_now` it would be very strange to add that to a form, since `auto_now` means that it should take the time when it is saved.