# How to edit the ctime of Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_num = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have `ctime` you see.

But in my `Order`'s update APIView:

```
class OrderUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsSuperAdminOrFinanceAdmin]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "order_num"
```

I can not edit the Order's `ctime` although the API return success.

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add ?

Comment: @Umair So, the ctime can not be edit, right?