# How create django model with timestamptz field

Tags: django, django-models

I have responce data from API it's look like this

```
{
  "api": {
    "results": 1,
    "fixtures": {
      "65": {
        "fixture_id": "65",
        "event_timestamp": "1533927600",
        "event_date": "2018-08-10T19:00:00+00:00",
        "league_id": "2",
        "round": "Premier League - 1",
        "homeTeam_id": "33",
        "awayTeam_id": "46",
        "homeTeam": "Manchester United",
        "awayTeam": "Leicester",
        "status": "Match Finished",
        "statusShort": "FT",
        "goalsHomeTeam": "2",
        "goalsAwayTeam": "1",
        "halftime_score": "1 - 0",
        "final_score": "2 - 1",
        "penalty": null,
        "elapsed": "95",
        "firstHalfStart": "1533927660",
        "secondHalfStart": "1533931380"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to build fixture model to store above data in PosgreSql database.  I dont understand didnt find any example of builded model with timestamptz field. I need to store event_date key in timestamptz.  Can anyone to show me how i should create this field

Answer (score 0):

Django does not have a default timestamp field. However, you can add one by having the following model field:

```
event_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**EDIT**

Or alternatively, something a little more up to date:

```
from django.utils import timezone
....
event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Make sure its `timezone.now` and not `timzone.now()`

Comment: For which purposes you added `auto_now_add = True` i find that is didnt recommend  look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737078/6053412