# Django: How to move from auto_add_now/auto_now to editable date fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We have a Model that includes an auto_add_now field and have decided that we need to be able to occasionally update it manually. However, in writing the DRF serializer / view it's unclear how best to handle this, since it's normally not editable we need to make a change.  We're considering using the pre-save trick (AutoDateTimeField): [Django auto_now and auto_now_add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add)  but that answer is 9 years old.

```
class AutoDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        return timezone.now()

#usage
created_at = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
updated_at = models.AutoDateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Are there any downsides? This is in an abstract base class which affects many models. Is there a better way (Django 1.11.7)?

Comment: AFAIK, **`auto_now_add`** field is ***not editable only in Django Admin***

Comment: Use this ```models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)``` now you can edit.

Comment: @JPG  Thanks. Didn't work in the Serializer/View context either, in my DRF code. Digging a little into the source code: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1410