# Inserting a 'hidden timestamp field' in a modelform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a simple form that allows a user to create a post. The fields are `post_title, post_content, post_date`. The `post_title` and `post_content` will be provided by the user, however the `post_date` will be autogenerated by the system and will give the current timestamp. Due to this, I will only show both `title` and `content` in the form. When I try and submit a request however, this gives me an IntegrityError saying `NOT NULL constraint failed: main_app_post.post_date`. I am fairly new at Django so I really have no idea what to do. I want it that whenever the user sends a Post request (and if it passes the validations), it will generate the current timestamp to `post_date` before saving it to the database. Any advices in regards of this? Thanks a lot!

**models.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_content = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

**forms.py:**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ('post_title', 'post_content')
```

**views.py:**

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post_title = form.cleaned_data['post_title']
            post_content = form.cleaned_data['post_content']
            post_date = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()

            form.post_date = post_date
            form.save(commit=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set [**`auto_now_add=True`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_content = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

**Refernce:** [Django `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add)

Comment: Thank you so much sir! That was quite simple! :')

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a `default` and make it non-editable, but in fact Django already has a solution for this: you can specify [**`auto_now_add=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_content = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```

This will make the field non-editable, so it will not show up in a form by default, and furthermore it will use as default value the current timestamp. This thus means that the view and form no longer have to worry about this.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D